# EFL / ESL language study books based on historical topics

Tags: resource-request, self-learning, english

I like history. Is there any EFL/ESL method which teaches English with historical subjects like WW2 or history in general?

I am looking for a book that is professionally designed for language learning with supplementary media contents and want to use it in my self-studying.

Comment: @Tommi. In this context from the word method I means book that is professionally designed for language learning with supplementary media contents. for me self-learning is the target.

Comment: I edited the question to take the comment into account. Please check it is still fine.